# Does putting a different quantifier changes the veracity of this linear algebra exercise?

Tags: linear-algebra, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

In this exercise, I'm asked to indicate - and justify - whether the following is true or not.

Let $A,B,C$ are matrices with real entries, with suitable dimensions. 
If $AC=BC$, then $A=B$.

My question is whether I should interpret this statement as $\exists C$ or $\forall C$.

In the case of $\exists C$, we can find $D\neq 0$, such that $DC=0$, making it possible to have $A\neq B$.

In the case of $\forall C$, then when we have $C=I$, we must have $A=B$. (edit: Completely wrong understanding of$\forall$ quantifier)

Am I right in this assessment?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let $A,B,C$..." means that $A,B,C$ may be any triple of matrices.

Thus you're asked to prove that
$$\forall A,\forall B, \forall C, (AC=BC\Rightarrow A=B)$$

This is clearly false (take $C=0$).

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was a really big one. =D